code ERESOLVE, ERESOLVE could not resolve, While resolving: react-native, Found: react, could not resolve dependency, conflicting peer dependency
i have an React native app running on Expo(49). Since the version quickly became deprecated and unusable with the expo go app, we need to upgrade the sdk. When we tried, the problems started growing.
I have an NPM Depencency Error. Im on Windows, and the typical flags --legacy-peer-deps and audit fix dont fix anything, more making it worse.
Does anyone know how to solve these dependency tree errors?
I already removed some deprecated packages, deleted node_modules and package-lock, changed package versions with a tool, but nothing works
Package.json:
{   
"name": "firstreactnativeapp",   
"version": "1.0.0",   
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",   
"scripts": {     
"start": "expo start",     
"android": "expo start --android",     
"ios": "expo start --ios",     
"web": "expo start --web"   
},   
"dependencies": {     
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",     
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.10",     
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",     
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.15",     
"@react-spring/native": "^9.5.5",     
"@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3",     
"@types/react": "~18.2.45",     
"expo": "^51.0.8",     
"expo-blur": "~13.0.2",     
"expo-linear-gradient": 
"~13.0.2",     
"expo-location": "~17.0.1",     
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",     
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",     
"firebase": "^10.5.2",     
"formik": "^2.4.5",     
"react": "^18.3.1",     
"react-native": "0.74.1",     
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",     
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",     
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",     
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",     
"react-native-webview": "13.8.6",     
"react-tinder-card": "^1.6.4"    
},   
"devDependencies": {     
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",     
"typescript": "^5.3.3"   
},   
"private": true 
} 

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE 
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native@0.74.1 
npm ERR! Found: react@18.3.1 
npm ERR! node_modules/react 
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-native/virtualized-lists@0.74.83 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native/virtualized-lists 
npm ERR!     @react-native/virtualized-lists@"0.74.83" from react-native@0.74.1 
pm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.20 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs 
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.5.10" from the root project 
npm ERR!   21 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/elements, ...) 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: 
npm ERR! peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.74.1 
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native 
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || >=0.60 <1.0" from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.23.1 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage 
npm ERR!     peerOptional @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@"^1.18.1" from @firebase/auth@1.7.4 
npm ERR!     node_modules/@firebase/auth 
npm ERR!       @firebase/auth@"1.7.4" from @firebase/auth-compat@0.5.9 
npm ERR!       node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat npm ERR!       1 more (firebase) 
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native/virtualized-lists@0.74.83 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native/virtualized-lists 
npm ERR!     @react-native/virtualized-lists@"0.74.83" from react-native@0.74.1 
npm ERR!   10 more (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs, ...) 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0 
npm ERR! node_modules/react 
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.74.1 
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native 
npm ERR!     peer react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || >=0.60 <1.0" from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.23.1 
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage 
npm ERR!       peerOptional @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@"^1.18.1" from @firebase/auth@1.7.4 
npm ERR!       node_modules/@firebase/auth 
npm ERR!         @firebase/auth@"1.7.4" from @firebase/auth-compat@0.5.9 
npm ERR!         node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat 
npm ERR!         1 more (firebase) 
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project) 
npm ERR!     peer react-native@"*" from @react-native/virtualized-lists@0.74.83 
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-native/virtualized-lists 
npm ERR!       @react-native/virtualized-lists@"0.74.83" from react-native@0.74.1 
npm ERR!     10 more (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs, ...) 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry 
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps 
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried updating from expo SDK49 to version 51 and expected to be working, but now i have npm dependency errors

Try this: npx expo install --fix
